# How to handle key in PHP array if the key contains japanese characters

Tags: php, arrays, character-encoding

I have this array:

```
[ID] => 荒川之下流三十景-その二十三「赤羽之景」__35.79_139.72
[Email] => 
[InBuildingAddress] => 
[Price] => 
[Street] => 
[Title] => 荒川之下流三十景 その二十三「赤羽之景」
[Website] => 
[Zip] => 
[Rating Star] => 0
[Rating Weight] => 0
[Latitude] => 35.7865334803033
[Longitude] => 139.716800710514
[Building] => 
[City] => Unknown_Japan
[OpeningHour] => 
[TimeStamp] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
[CountViews] => 0
```

Then I do something like this:

```
    $output[$info['ID']] = $info; //mess up here
    $tes = $info['ID']['Title'];
```

Well guess what: it messes up. The reason why it may mess up is because $info['ID'] is not ascii. Yet I am using it as a key for $output[$info['ID']].

Basically even though the content of an array in PHP can be Japanese. Is this true?

What's wrong? The error I got is:

Debug Warning: /sdfdsfdf/api/test2.php line 36 - Cannot find element ????????-???????????__35.79_139.72 in variable
Debug Warning: /sdfdsfdf/api/test2.php line 36 - main() [function.main]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'Asia/Krasnoyarsk' for '7.0/no DST' instead

So many question marks.

Why is this happening? What's really going on inside PHP? Where can I learn more of such things? Most importantly, what would be the best way to handle this situation? Should I tell PHP to internally always use UTF-8? Can PHP arrays inherently not have non-ASCII values?

Comment: Which line is line 36? I'm not sure why there would be a concern about time-zones on the two lines you gave above.

Comment: *"Then I do something like this"*. So, what do *really* you do then? Because currently, its extremely far fetched that code you posted would generate any error message from that.

Comment: Far fetched? That's EXACTLY what I did. I am using Zend Debugger. It looks like the error is only in the debugger. I can't browse the array. So it could just be a bug in Zend. I can still print_r. The reason why it may mess up is because $info['ID'] is not ascii.

Comment: I do not know why the timezone setting error show up. I thought it's related to this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running this:

```
$utf8str = '荒川之下流三十景-その二十三「赤羽之景」__35.79_139.72';
$arr = Array(
    $utf8str => $utf8str,
);
var_dump($arr);


$arr[$utf8str] = "test";
var_dump($arr);
```

I get this:

```
array
  '荒川之下流三十景-その二十三「赤羽之景」__35.79_139.72' => string '荒川之下流三十景-その二十三「赤羽之景」__35.79_139.72' (length=72)

array
  '荒川之下流三十景-その二十三「赤羽之景」__35.79_139.72' => string 'test' (length=4)
```

So **PHP can handle utf8 charachers as the array key**...

---

Regarding the `date` related warning, please use google first, its faster that asking questions and waiting for people to come up with answers to the same questions over and over (is suppose thats the reason you got downvoted)

[google search](https://www.google.ro/search?q=It%20is%20not%20safe%20to%20rely%20on%20the%20system%27s%20timezone%20settings.%20You%20are%20required%20to%20use%20the%20date.timezone%20setting%20or%20the%20date_default_timezone_set)

Comment: There should be no error too then on my original code. Never mind then. It works fine.